# Django Rest Framework - Envelope a Paginated Response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination, metadata

I want to wrap an paginated response in an envelope. The Result should look like this.

```
{
    "data": ["datum 1", "datum 2", "datum 3"],
    "meta": {
        "some": "meta",
        "data": "foo",
    },
    "page": {
        "total": 12345,
        "count": 3,
        "from": 3,
        "to": 6,
        "next": "http://example.com?page=2",
        "prev": "http://example.com?page=0",
    }
}
```

The custom page format can be achieved by inheriting from PageNumberPagination.
My question is about passing the Metadata. I do not see any way to pass it to the Pagination except some form of in band signaling. Is there a clean(er) way to do this?

Comment: What kind of metadata do you need to pass. I think you can inject metadata when you are inheriting from PageNumberPagination, like in their example, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#example

Comment: An example would be the Version of the Api. Another would be a transaction id. The first one could be statically embedded, but the second one is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    view = None

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        self.view = view
        return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)

    def get_meta(self, data=None, **meta):
        return {
            'data_from_view': self.view.__class__.__name__,
            'static_data': settings.ROOT_URLCONF,
            'len_per_page': len(data),
            'dynamic_data_on_thy_fly': meta
        }

    def get_paginated_response(self, data, **meta):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'meta': self.get_meta(data, **meta),
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })
```

Comment: You should override the **`paginate_queryset(...)`**  method of corresponding view